# Read n lines from the end backward in python

Tags: python

i have a text file which contains 5 lines.

```
this is line 1.
this is line 2.
this is line 3.
this is line 4.
this is line 5.
```

1. i want to print all the lines in backward order. i.e

```
this is line 5.
this is line 4.
this is line 3.
this is line 2.
this is line 1.
```

2. i want to print lines in random order.

i was trying

```
import string
import random

def readingLinesBackwards(filename):
    inputFile = open(test.txt, 'r')

    newFileName = "linesBackwards_" + poemFileName
    outputFile = open(newFileName.txt, 'w')
    inputFile.readline()
    for nextLine in inputFile:
        #nextLine = nextLine.strip()
        allLines.append(nextLine)

    # close the input (original) file
    inputFile.close()

    # now reverse the lines in the list
    allLines.reverse()
    for line in allLines:
        outputFile.write(line)
    # end of for loop

    print("\t" + newFileName +" created.\n")

    outputFile.close()
    return None
```

I am not sure if .reverse() will work
Is there any way to randomize the lines ?

Comment: You do not need to `import string`.

Comment: @meyer9 is there a simple alternative to do this?

Comment: indent your code properly please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comments and help inline below.

```
import random
import os.path

# consolidate common code even for simple apps
def write_lines_to_file(filename, lines):
    with open(filename, 'w') as output:
        output.writelines(lines)
    # Use format strings
    # Hint: print() appends a newline by default. The '\n'
    #       here is a second one.
    print("\t{} created.\n".format(filename))

def do_backwards_and_reverse(filename):
    # Use with to automatically close files...
    with open(filename) as input:
        # readlines(), i.e. no need to read line by line
        lines = input.readlines()

    # for completeness since you're modifying the filename,
    # check to see if there are any path components
    dirname, basename = os.path.split(filename)

    # how to put a path back together
    new_filename = os.path.join(dirname, "lines_backwards_" + basename)
    # the reversed() builtin returns a new reversed list
    # consolidating common code into a re-usable function is a
    # good idea even for simple code like this
    write_lines_to_file(new_filename, reversed(lines))

    new_filename = os.path.join(dirname, "lines_and_words_backwards_" + basename)
    # Create a temporary function (using the lambda keyword) that takes
    # an argument, line, splits it into pieces by whitespace, reverses the
    # pieces, joins them back together with a single space between, and
    # finally appends a newline.
    reverse_words_in_line = lambda line: ' '.join(reversed(line.split())) + '\n'
    # Create a generator (like a list, but faster) of lines in reverse
    # order with each line's words in reverse order.
    altered_lines = (reverse_words_in_line(line) for line in reversed(lines))
    # Pass the generator because almost everything in Python that
    # takes a list is really built to take anything that can be iterated
    write_lines_to_file(new_filename, altered_lines)

    new_filename = os.path.join(dirname, "lines_randomized_" + basename)
    # randomly shuffle a list inplace... which means this has to come
    # last because unlike above where we return new modified lists,
    # shuffle() modifies the list of lines itself. If we want the
    # original order back, we'll have to re-read the original file.
    random.shuffle(lines)
    write_lines_to_file(new_filename, lines)
```

Comment: Sir, i am getting the right result! Thanks, If possible, while printing lines in reverse order can, words too be printed from end to start in reverse order. 
for eg.  `5 line is this` `4 line is this` and so on.

Comment: Accept the answer if it's what you want. Also, open a python interpreter and try each of the lines in the solution by hand so you can see how it all works.

Answer (score 2):

To output the lines in reverse order:

```
# take the lines from the input file and put them into a list
inputFile = open("input.txt","r")
lines = inputFile.readlines()
inputFile.close()

# reverse the list of lines
lines.reverse()

# write the reversed lines into the output file
outputFile = open("output.txt","w")
for line in lines:
    outputFile.write(line)
outputFile.close()
```

Comment: A possibly more pythonic way of doing this would be to just use list slices and do `lines[::-1]`, which would remove the need to reverse the list.

Comment: `reversed(iterable)` is even better since it doesn't create a new list.

Comment: Use `with` statements for the files, drop the `'r'` from `open()` as it's the default, and use `outputFile.writelines()`.

Answer (score 1):

for printing in random order,
you can use

```
import random

list = inputFile.readlines().splitlines()
randlist = list
random.shuffle(randlist)

for line in randlist:
    print line

#for reverse
for line in list.reverse():
    print line
```

Comment: Sir, i am getting the right result! Thanks, If possible, while printing lines in reverse order can, words too be printed from end to start. 
for eg.  `5 line is this` `4 line is this` and so on.

Answer (score 0):

First read all of your lines in using `readlines()` to create a list of lines. To get the lines in reversed order, use a slice as `[::-1]`. Use `join()` to join all these lines back together into a single string and write it to `backwards.txt`. Finally use Python's `random.shuffle()` to randomly change the order of your list of lines, and then join and write these to another file. By using `with`, it ensures the files are all closed automatically (so you don't need to add `close()`).

```
import random    

with open('input.txt') as f_input:
    lines = f_input.readlines()

with open('backwards.txt', 'w') as f_backwards:
    f_backwards.write(''.join(lines[::-1]))

with open('random.txt', 'w') as f_random:
    random.shuffle(lines)
    f_random.write(''.join(lines))
```

If you just want to print, then replace with something like:

```
print ''.join(lines[::-1])
```