# Python: print last line of text file first and first line last (reverse)

Tags: python

I'd like to take a .txt file and paste the contents into a Multiline element, last line first - first line last, using PySimpleGUI.

The problem is, I want the file to print from the last line to the first.
e.g.

```
line1
line2
line3
line4
line5
```

would print

```
line5
line4
line3
line2
line1
```

I've tried

```
with open('file.txt','r') as f:
  x=f.read()
print(reversed(x))
```

and

```
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
  x=f.read()
print(x[::-1]
```

but both just invert/reverse everything. I want to print the last line first and the last line last but in the order that the characters initially appear.

I get something like

```
5enil
4enil
3enil
...
```

Comment: Your example would be more helpful with more than 3 lines.

Comment: Where did the contents of `x` come from?

Comment: `f.read()` just gives you one long string of characters. you'll want to split that on newline (e.g. directly by using `x = f.readlines()`), then reverse the resulting list.

Comment: Hi Scott, I've updated my post so hopefully it's more coherent.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Read n lines from the end backward in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42991963/read-n-lines-from-the-end-backward-in-python)

Comment: Thanks FObersteiner, do you know how I can do this without the ```readlines()``` function?

Comment: jonsca   Yeah this looks exactly like what I want, I'll have a read. Thanks!!! I googles for ages and didn't find this.

Comment: @IKnowNothing It's okay, I had to search around a bit for it myself.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [readlines](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects) like this:

```py
lines = []
with open("lines", "r") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

print("".join((reversed(lines))))
```

Output

```
line5
line4
line3
line2
line1
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code:

```
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
   x=f.readlines()
   print(x[::-1])
```

It's working.

Answer (score 0):

[Could use the `readlines()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html)

```py
# '''this is line 1\nthis is line 2\nthis is line 3'''

with open('test_text.txt', 'r') as f:
    last_line = f.readlines()[-1]
    first_line = f.readlines()[0]

print(first_line)
print(last_line)
```

output

```
'this is line 1'
'this is line 3'
```

Answer (score 0):

you can this

```
print("\n".join (reversed(open('list.txt',"r").read().splitlines())))
```